# Why does google chrome completely disallow microphone access in a server?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, webcam

I am hosting a html file using a server hosted from a python script. The html file includes some sort of speech recognition, so it needs the microphone.

I open the html file using the google chrome web browser. To access the html file, I type in an ip address with a specific port (unmentioned due to privacy). Now, for some reason, the site settings completely disallow me to even change the microphone access (see screenshot below). Does anyone know a possible reason for why this occurs?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome blocks vulnerable features, including camera, location, microphone, etc. on non-secure sites. As of July 2018, with the release of Chrome 68,
[Chrome starts to mark all HTTP sites as "not secure"](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/marking-http-as-non-secure).

You have three options to unblock these features for your site:

- Treat your URL, for example `192.168.10.79`, as secure origins by setting `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`.
  Specify the protocol, e.g. `http://192.168.10.79`.
- Port forward your site address to `localhost`, which Chrome treats
  as secure origins.
- Set up a self-signed certificate for the server.